# database design for updating data weekly

Tags: mysql, database

I find it very difficult to explain what I want to ask, So I created a hypothetical question (taking ex of temp), Maybe my question is still not very clear, But pls take a look. let me know if you need any clarification

I want to compare the temp of last Sunday and temp of temp 3 weeks ago (Sunday),
So it should show something like this. There would be two dates in select option so I want to analyze temp on Sunday before last Sunday,

```html
<select>
 <option> Last  Sunday (2017-12-03) </option>
 <option> Previous Sunday (2017-11-26) </option>
</select>

<h1> Temp on 2017-12-03 </h1>

<p> 24 C </p>


<h1> temp 3 weeks ago (2017-11-12)</h1>

<p> 24.4 C</p>

<h1> Change in temp </h1>

<p> .4 </p>
```

Assume I can get the temp only current Sunday, So I need to update this database on weekly basis (on every sunday)

```
city_id    sunday_temp   temp_pre_week1   temp_pre_week2  temp_pre_week3 last_sunday_date  
  1          24.0                24.3              35.2               24.4   2017-12-03            
 1           24.3                35.2               24.4               28.0  2017-11-26               
 2           3.0                 4.0                2.0                6.0  2017-12-03            
 2           4.0                 2.0                6.0                7.0  2017-11-26               
 .
 .
around 2000 rows
```

Another option that i thought would be saving the data for 4 weeks, So when user select the Sunday before last Sunday I would be able to use 4th-week column,
Something like this

```
city_id    sunday_temp   temp_pre_week1   temp_pre_week2   temp_pre_week3  temp_pre_week4 last_sunday_date  
 1           24.0                24.3              35.2           24.4       28.0              2017-12-03                      
 2           3.0                 4.0                2.0           6.0        7.0               2017-12-03                      
 .
 .
```

I only want to  analyze two Sundays not more than that, So i think adding one more column would be more efficient,

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't store all the data for a query in each row. Let the database do the work for you. Your database structure should just include `city_id`, `date`,`temp`. If you only have Sundays included, that's OK. You can then use something like

```
SELECT `temp`,`date` FROM `citydata` WHERE (`city_id` = 1) and (`date` <= '2017-12-03') ORDER BY `date` DESC LIMIT 4
```

which will retrieve the last 4 records available for city 1 that are on or before 2017-12-03. If you have data for every Sunday, that will get you the specific date ("last Sunday") plus the 3 previous weeks. If you decide you want more - just change the LIMIT to 5 or 6 or whatever you want. If you later decide to add different days of the week you won't have to change the database structure (though you will need to adjust your queries a bit). Most importantly, you won't need to look to previous records when you are collecting new data - you just add the new records and get the previous weeks of data when you actually need them.

Comment: Hi, Thank you so much for your Answer,  But i am still confused, If i have only three columns that mean i will have around 10000 rows for 2000 cities ,  But if i use 6 columns i will have only 2000 rows and city_id will be unique,  So what is better here "6 columns 2000 rows" OR "3 columns 10000 rows", Please let me know,  I don't wanna change the database later so Limit 5 Limit 6 really not important for me

Comment: 1 - city_id won't be unique either way. city_id + date will be unique with both structures. 2 - My suggestion will result in more rows. But each row will be much simpler. The complexity will go to the query, but the insert process will be simpler. With your original method, each time you add a new city/date you have to look back to previous records to find each of the 3 (or 4 or whatever) previous temps to include in the new record. With my method each insert is very simple and requires no reading of old data. The user query is more complex but also MUCH more flexible.